# Will stacking 2 peltier coolers on top of each other reach a lower temperature quicker?

Tags: thermodynamics, electronics, thermoelectricity

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to get freezing (<0 degrees Celsius) temperature as quickly as possible. Clearly, stacking 2 peltier coolers on top of each other will be less efficient than only having one, and the whole thing will heat up quicker, but if I only want to reach a below freezing temperature within <5 seconds and stay there for at least 5 seconds, would it be more beneficial to only have a heatsink and 1 peltier cooler, or to have the same heat sink, and 2 peltier coolers on top of each other? Thanks.

Comment: What is the heat capacity of your object, and what are the cooler(s) and heat sinks rated for? So, how much heat do you need to move?

Comment: The thing I'm trying to cool is really small and made out of metal, so its heat is probably negligible. I do no know what the heatsink is rated for because it's just an old heatsink from a computer. This is probably better for me to just test with an experiment, but thanks anyway.